# How can I use the SerialIP library on my Arduino through a Mac?

Tags: serial, tcpip

I am looking into using the [SerialIP library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SerialIP) to connect my Arduino to the internet through it's USB connection to my computer.

However, I cannot figure out how to establish the SLIP connection to the Arduino from my Mac.

The library's documentation says:

> Perhaps the most difficult part of using this library is figuring out
>   how to establish the SLIP connection to the Arduino.

It suggests the use of:

```
sudo slattach -L -s 115200 -p slip /dev/ttyUSB0
```

On linux systems. However, on my Mac running OS X 10.10, there is no such command.

I ran into [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2491031?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple forums regarding the missing `slattach` command, which sounds like it was removed in OS X 10.6.

How can I use the SerialIP Arduino library on my Mac?

Comment: You might see if there is a homebrew or macports version of that?